# apollo server pagination list only items recently fetched from cache or network

Tags: reactjs, graphql, pagination, apollo

I'm using react, graphql, and apollo. I've implemented a server side paginated table. The problem is that when I page forward, and the new items come in from the network request (correctly) they are rendered as appended to the existing items in the table.

The behavior I expect would be that the newly fetched items only are rendered, and then if I page back again the original items should be displayed (from the cache).

Now, reading the apollo docs on this matter I see that this is standard behavior I guess. [From the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/data/pagination/#:%7E:text=In%20Apollo%2C%20the%20easiest%20way,result%20into%20the%20original%20result.): "Once the new data is returned from the server, the updateQuery function is used to merge it with the existing data, which will cause a re-render of your UI component with an expanded list."

But I have not been able to find a way to implement the behavior I want (which is an extremely common pagination pattern)

Here is the code I have:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);
  const [sortField, setSortField] = useState('name');
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<Order>('ASC');
  const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
    { field: 'name', sort: 'asc' },
  ]);

  const { data } = useQuery(Document, {
    variables: {
      id,,
      input: {
        count: 25,
        page: page + 1,
        sort: sortField,
        order: sortOrder,
      },
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });

  const handleSortModelChange = useCallback((model: GridSortModel) => {
    const { field = 'name', sort = 'ASC' } = model[0] || {};
    const order = sort?.toUpperCase() as Order;
    setSortModel(model);
    setSortField(field);
    setSortOrder(order);
  }, []);

  const handlePageChange = useCallback((newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  }, []);
```

I have verified that it is not an issue with the table implementation or other UI code by rendering the raw data and inspecting the results when I paginate

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this in what I think was a non-optimal way. I had to add a custom merge function in the typePolicies for the field on which the pagination was being performed. The code is as follows:

```
merge(existing, incoming: MyListType) {
  // If "existing" is present, then perform array merging. Otherwise, return "incoming" as is.
  return existing
    ? {
        ...incoming,
        items: [
          ...existing.items.filter(
            (existingItem) =>
              !incoming.items.find(
                (item) => item.id === existingItem.id
              )
          ),
          ...incoming.items,
        ],
      }
    : incoming;
},
```

And in my query:

```
fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
```

That said, it seems strange that I needed to make a custom merge function in my typePolicies config in order to get Apollo to handle such a common use case (server pagination without lazy load and server sort). If anyone knows an easier way I'd love to be enlightened in a comment or another solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the the `fetchMore` function is used to fetch additional data without merging it with the existing data. The `updateQuery` function is set to `(prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => fetchMoreResult` to replace the existing data with the newly fetched data.

```
//modified version of your file

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);
  const [sortField, setSortField] = useState('name');
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<Order>('ASC');
  const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
    { field: 'name', sort: 'asc' },
  ]);

  const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery(Document, {
    variables: {
      id,
      input: {
        count: 25,
        page: page + 1,
        sort: sortField,
        order: sortOrder,
      },
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    // Use 'cache-and-network' to fetch data from the cache and send a network request
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network', 
  });

  const handleSortModelChange = useCallback((model: GridSortModel) => {
    const { field = 'name', sort = 'ASC' } = model[0] || {};
    const order = sort?.toUpperCase() as Order;
    setSortModel(model);
    setSortField(field);
    setSortOrder(order);
  }, []);

  const handlePageChange = useCallback((newPage: number) => {
    // Use fetchMore to fetch additional data without merging it with existing data
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        input: {
          count: 25,
          page: newPage + 1,
          sort: sortField,
          order: sortOrder,
        },
      },
      updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => fetchMoreResult,
    });
    setPage(newPage);
  }, [fetchMore, sortField, sortOrder]);


  return (
    // Your JSX code comes here
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Let me know if this works.